# Nginx proxy_pass configuration question in addition to custom error

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm configuring nginx as a reverse proxy and below is my configuration file. I want to proxy the requests coming to the nginx server(abc.com), to the domain example.com for example abc.com/api/hello ---> example.com/api/hello. Main reason for this is to avoid authentication for example.com.  Below snippet works fine for my current use case.

But now there is an use case such that my nginx has to return HTTP 404 for the requests coming to path "/". Can some one guide how to handle both HTTP 404 and reverse proxy conditions ?

```html
server{
    listen 80;
    root public;
    index index.html index.htm Default.htm;
    location /health
    {
      root data;
      index index.html index.htm Default.htm;

    }
    location / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/;
    proxy_set_header Cookie "";
    proxy_set_header Authorization "";
    proxy_set_header xxxxxxxxx "true";
    proxy_hide_header Cookie;

  }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean ANY requet to your NGINX instance need to have some location like /api/something and if somebody tries to call / you need to send a 404?

Comment: Hello Timo,
Yes if any request to nginx with / has to responded with 404 and other requests will some URI path has to go the proxy_pass domain.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as the first location block

```
location = / {
return 404;
}
```